# What color is the hemolymph of the Japanese giant hornet?

Tags: entomology

This is a random and very specific question that's been nagging me for quite some time. I've tried asking on other websites with no luck, and am hoping that somebody here can either give me an answer or redirect me to somebody/somewhere where I can get my answer. I guess it isn't required but I'd also prefer to know, if you can give me an answer, how you got your knowledge on it. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: We may never know. Every scientist brave enough to attempt an answer to this question has died from giant hornet attacks.

Comment: Well, if anybody lives in Japan then I kindly ask you to cut open a dead one if you find it...

Comment: Would it be different from other insects' hemolymph?

Comment: Yeah. Spider (an arachnid, but still a valid example)  hemolymph is blue because of copper, whereas some insects have hemolymph that is yellow or green.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure this out for myself by watching videos of the hornets being eaten by other insects. The answer is that the hemolymph is a pale yellow color, like I've heard other wasps and some bees have as well.